# How to get all/some files (CloudBlockBlob) from an Azure blob container?

Tags: azure, blob, containers

I know I can get a specific file from an Azure blob container using its name, like this:
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob.txt");

Is there a way to get all the files in a List? I would like to do something like this, but unfortunately there is no such method:
CloudBlockBlob blockBlobList = container.**GetBlockBlobReferences**("*.*");

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in getting a list of all blobs in a container, you can certainly do that.

```
var container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
var blobs = container.ListBlobs();
```

`blobs` variable will have a list of all blobs.

Comment: @Guarav Mantri ... And what if you only want a list of blobs in a subfolder of the container, for example... container/folder1/folder2

Comment: @dinotom You can still use ListBlobs method. Please include `container/folder1/folder2` as `prefix`. See this for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If it's CloudBlockBlobs that you want, casting could help.

```
var container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
var blobs = container.ListBlobs().Cast<CloudBlockBlob>();
```